# Rails has_many with direct and indirect association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-design

I've three models: Category, Line and Product.

Category has lines.
Line has products.
And product can belongs to Category directly too.

So I've two association variations:

1 - `Category -> Line -> Product`
2 - `Category -> Product`

How can I implement this using `has_many`?

Of course, I can't declare two `has_many` like this:

```
# category.rb
has_many :lines
has_many :products, through: :lines
has_many :products
```

Comment: If product can belong to category directly why didn't you try something like `has_many :lines` and `has_many :products` ?

Comment: @Kiloreux Because I want to have access to the products through the lines too

Answer (score 4):

You should probably set it up like this:

```
has_many :lines
has_many :line_products, through: lines, source: products
has_many :products
```

With `:source`, we're telling Rails to look for an association called `:products` on the Line model and use that.

You can also check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference for some more information.

Comment: I want to keep a unique interface to access the products.  
In the end I associate **all** products directly with the categories.

Comment: And the association with lines are optional.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming we're trying to build a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products
  LEFT OUTER JOIN lines ON products.line_id = lines.id
  WHERE lines.category_id = <category_id> 
    OR products.category_id = <category_id>;
```

In `Category`, we could create an instance method rather than using associations:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def products
     Product.eager_load(:line)
      .where("products.category_id = :id OR lines.category_id = :id", {id: id})
  end
end
```

But if associations are really your thing, something like this might work (I'm not 100% sure):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, ->(category) { 
    reset.eager_load(:line)
      .where("products.category_id = :id OR lines.category_id = :id", {id: category.id})
  }
end
```